# Bash find command verbose output

Tags: linux, bash, find

Is there way to tell the bash `find` command to output what it is doing (verbose mode)?

For example for the command:
`find /media/1Tb/videos -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;` to output:

```
Found /media/1Tb/videos/102, executing rm -rf /media/1Tb/videos/102
...
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You could concoct something with `-printf`, but the easiest is just to tack on `-print` on the end. This will show what was successfully deleted.

Comment: this answer can be applied to anything when using `find`, so thumbs up

Comment: my `find` love grew another just another little bit. thanks :)

Comment: For me, using "-exec rm -vf {} \;" worked better.

Comment: Nice! Works with -delete too: 
`find -L . -type l -delete -print`

Comment: Here is an example to let the find output look like `rm -v`'s output: `find "$path" -delete -printf "removed '%p'\n"`

Answer (score 26):

How about just using `rm -vf` for verbose rm output.

```
$ touch file1 file2 file3
$ find . -name "file?" -exec rm -vf {} \;
removed `./file2'
removed `./file3'
removed `./file1'
```

Comment: the verbose option for `rm` is cool but if I replaced it with something else I can no longer see what files are being worked on (unless I use `echo` inside `-exec`)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to let the commands be executed by `sh -x`:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 echo rm | sh -x
+ rm ./file1
+ rm ./file2
+ rm ./file3
```

Comment: `shell` `debug` mode will be clear enough on what has happened. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is also `find -D xxxx` that could help in some cases.

```
 $ find -D help
 Valid arguments for -D:
 help       Explain the various -D options
 tree       Display the expression tree
 search     Navigate the directory tree verbosely
 stat       Trace calls to stat(2) and lstat(2)
 rates      Indicate how often each predicate succeeded
 opt        Show diagnostic information relating to optimisation
 exec       Show diagnostic information relating to -exec, -execdir, -ok and -okdir
```

Below are two examples of `find -D search`:

Using RHEL 6.3 (`find` v4.4):

```
$ mkdir -p aa/bb
$ touch aa/11 aa/22 aa/33 aa/bb/44 aa/bb/55
$ find -D search aa -type f -delete
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0, prev_depth=-2147483648 fts_path=`aa', fts_accpath=`aa'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 1, prev_depth=0 fts_path=`aa/bb', fts_accpath=`bb'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 2, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`aa/bb/55', fts_accpath=`55'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 2, prev_depth=2 fts_path=`aa/bb/44', fts_accpath=`44'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=2 fts_path=`aa/bb', fts_accpath=`bb'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`aa/22', fts_accpath=`22'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`aa/33', fts_accpath=`33'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`aa/11', fts_accpath=`11'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`aa', fts_accpath=`aa'
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX FTS() CBO(level=0)
```

Using Cygwin 1.7 (`find` 4.5):

```
$ mkdir -p aa/bb
$ touch aa/11 aa/22 aa/33 aa/bb/44 aa/bb/55
$ find -D search aa -type f -delete
consider_visiting (early): 'aa': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0, prev_depth=-2147483648 fts_path='aa', fts_accpath='aa'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignore=1 have_stat=1 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/11': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=0 fts_path='aa/11', fts_accpath='11'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/11': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, isdir=0 ignore=0 have_stat=0 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/22': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path='aa/22', fts_accpath='22'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/22': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, isdir=0 ignore=0 have_stat=0 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/33': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path='aa/33', fts_accpath='33'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/33': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, isdir=0 ignore=0 have_stat=0 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/bb': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path='aa/bb', fts_accpath='bb'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/bb': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignore=1 have_stat=1 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/bb/44': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 2, prev_depth=1 fts_path='aa/bb/44', fts_accpath='44'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/bb/44': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, isdir=0 ignore=0 have_stat=0 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/bb/55': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 2, prev_depth=2 fts_path='aa/bb/55', fts_accpath='55'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/bb/55': fts_info=FTS_NSOK, isdir=0 ignore=0 have_stat=0 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa/bb': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=2 fts_path='aa/bb', fts_accpath='bb'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa/bb': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ignore=0 have_stat=1 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): 'aa': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0, prev_depth=1 fts_path='aa', fts_accpath='aa'
consider_visiting (late): 'aa': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ignore=0 have_stat=1 have_type=1
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
Packaged by Cygwin (4.5.11-1)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

@hlovdav's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/319411/237665) was enough for me but I did some modifications for my own use

```
find . -name 'application*.yml' -print0 | xargs -0 -I %% bash -c 'rm -v "$1"' -- "%%"
```

Explanation

1. find
2. `pattern`
3. Print `null` separated, important if you have filenames with spaces or unusual characters in it
4. `xargs` read `null` separated, set each record placeholder to `%%`
   This also ensures every time it uses only one argument
5. `bash` command, one-liner, anything goes inside, must be single quoted `'`
6. `--` meaning anything I do after this is not `xargs` or `bash` options but positional parameters to my one-liner script
7. Placeholder is given as single argument by quoting it, single or double quote doesn't matter. If you use double quotes, you can insert shell variables, too.
8. Inside `bash` script, you can access `%%` as `$1`, positional argument No #1

Note: You can change `%%` with anything, just make sure you don't need to use it for anything other than a placeholder. Using dollar `$` or `@` might not be good, unless it's double `@` like `@@`.